# Can't update object in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to update my object in Room by id, but it doesn't work.

Here is my DAO class

```
 @Query("UPDATE greeting SET id =:id")
    abstract fun updateGreetingByID(id: String)
```

Here is my DBHelper

```
  fun updateGreetingByID(id: String) {
        Thread { dataBase.greetingDao().updateGreetingByID(id) }.start()
    }
```

My model

```
@Entity(tableName = "greeting")
class GreetingModel(
    id: String? = "",
    greetingCategory: String = "",
    isFavourite: Boolean = false,
    position: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var _id: Int = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "greetingCategory")
    var greetingCategory: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "isFavourite")
    var isFavourite: Boolean? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageId")
    var imageId: ByteArray? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "position")
    var position: Int = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "saved")
    var saved: Int = 0

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    ) {
        _id = parcel.readInt()
        id = parcel.readString()
        greetingCategory = parcel.readString()
        isFavourite = parcel.readValue(Boolean::class.java.classLoader) as? Boolean
        imageId = parcel.createByteArray()
        position = parcel.readInt()
        saved = parcel.readInt()
    }


    init {
        this.id = id
        this.greetingCategory = greetingCategory
        if (position != null) {
            this.position = position
        }
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(_id)
        parcel.writeString(id)
        parcel.writeString(greetingCategory)
        parcel.writeValue(isFavourite)
        parcel.writeByteArray(imageId)
        parcel.writeInt(position)
        parcel.writeInt(saved)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<GreetingModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): GreetingModel {
            return GreetingModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GreetingModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```

Where `id`  is `val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

I want to update object when user click to favourite button

```
 val greetingModel = GreetingModel()
                    greetingModel.isFavourite = true
                    greetingModel.greetingCategory = " "
                    greetingModel.position = postImage


                    greetingModel.id?.let { helper.updateGreetingByID(greetingModel.id!!) }
```

My `update` method doesn't work. Hope, you will help!

Comment: It looks as though you are using an id that is highly unlikely to exist as randomUUID will get a *type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.* You have something 1^122 chance of getting the correct id, if there is more than 1 other row in the database you have more chance of updating the wrong row. However in all likelihood you have little chance of updating any row, even with millions of rows.  You need to retrieve the id of the respective object that is to be updated not pass a randomly generated id.

Comment: Thank you for your reply) I just set the wrong id and my greetingModel.id was null. I change it and my problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to update according to a newly constructed Greeting that has the id as whatever value the id is set to when the Greeting is constructed using the default (no parameters constructor).

The fix is to retrieve the specific id of the Greeting that was clicked and set the id to that value before doing the update.

Comment: I already set the specific id and my problem solved. Thank you for your reply:)